# how to retrieve value from an object-java

Tags: java, object, elliptic-curve

i need to know how to access value of an object..for example in my code
`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws  Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
      BigInteger ZERO=new BigInteger("0");
       int c;
     ECCurve curve = new ECCurve.Fp(
            newBigInteger("883423532389192164791648750360308885314476597252960362792450860609699839"), // q new BigInteger("7fffffffffffffffffffffff7fffffffffff8000000000007ffffffffffc", 16), // a new BigInteger("6b016c3bdcf18941d0d654921475ca71a9db2fb27d1d37796185c2942c0a", 16)); // b

ECParameterSpec ecSpec = new ECParameterSpec(
           curve,
            curve.decodePoint( Hex.decode("020ffa963cdca8816ccc33b8642bedf905c3d358573d3f27fbbd3b3cb9aaaf")), // G
            new BigInteger("883423532389192164791648750360308884807550341691627752275345424702807307")); // n
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");
kpg.initialize(ecSpec, new SecureRandom());
KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
PublicKey pubKey = keyPair.getPublic();
System.out.println(pubKey);
PrivateKey privKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
System.out.println(privKey);`
```

int y=numNoRange+p;//where p is value of privatekey..here along with the number i need to add privatekey  value,but private is object,so i need to know how to retrieve value from the object..Thank you..

Comment: You are trying to know the value in privJKey(which is object of PrivateKey class)?

Answer (score 0):

if you know what kind of an object p is; then just cast it. then get the value
here is a simple example of casting from double to int

```
double d = 3.5;
int x = (int) d;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`PublicKey`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/PublicKey.html) is a base class for representing a public key of an asymmetric cryptographic algorithm. By it's nature it's rather a structure, than a single value.

For example, if you work with RSA algorithm, then you can cast your public key to
`RSAPublicKey` and then access `modulus` and `exponent`.

```
if (pubKey instanceof RSAPublicKey) {
    RSAPublicKey rsaPubKey = (RSAPublicKey)pubKey;
    BigInteger modulus = rsaPubKey.getModulus();
    BigInteger exponent = rsaPubKey.getPublicExponent();
    System.out.println("Modulus " + modulus.toString());
    System.out.println("Exponent " + exponent.toString());
}
```

For elliptic curve cryptography the key consist of two values - parameters of an elliptic curve `affineX` and `affineY`

```
if (pubKey instanceof ECPublicKey) {
    ECPublicKey ecPubKey = (ECPublicKey)pubKey;
    ECPoint point = ecPubKey.getW();
    BigInteger affineX = point.getAffineX();
    BigInteger affineY = point.getAffineY();
    System.out.println("Affine X " + affineX.toString());
    System.out.println("Affine Y " + affineY.toString());
}
```

The same way internal structure of [`PrivateKey`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/PrivateKey.html) can be accessed.